# Platform independent Screensavers with Qt

Tags: qt, screensaver

Has anyone tried a platform independent screensaver with Qt. My target systems are Win and Mac, and before digging further I was wondering if it possible with not too much fiddling with native calls ... Thanks!

Comment: I doubt it - there's no API in Qt for it, and integrating screensavers is inherently windowmanager-specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Andi Peredri* [wrote an article](http://qt.osdn.org.ua/screensaver.en.html) about developing a screensaver for KDE in 2004 using Qt 3.2 to build **QStars**.

[image]

The article shares source code, but the link in the article is outdated. The most recent version is [available here](http://qt.osdn.org.ua/qstars-0.4.tar.gz) (2005).